# Only one time execute - AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This AJAX only execute only **one time** and If you are clicked once, AJAX does not work for other "Details" buttons. What is the reason of this?

Buttons:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a id="detay-menu-toggle-right" data-paketno="3512" href="#">Details</a></td>
<td><a id="detay-menu-toggle-right" data-paketno="3841" href="#">Details</a></td>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#detay-menu-toggle-right").click(function(){
        $("#detay-wrapper-right").toggleClass("active");
        var paketnosu = $(this).data("paketno");
        var dataString = 'paketDetayi='+paketnosu;
        $.ajax({
            data: dataString,
            url: 'test3.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#detay-sidebar-wrapper-right").html(data);
            },
            error:
                function() {
                    alert('Not OKay');
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: You should make your tag id's unique. You are using the same tag id more than once. Change those id to a class if you need them more than once.

Comment: @alfredo I changed the IDs but the result did not change

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan Unfortunately no error record

Comment: How do you know that the call is only happening once? Are you sure it's not that the call is returning the exact same data on subsequent calls? If you open your developer tools (F12) and click on the Network tab and then make the calls, do you see only the initial call getting made or do you see the subsequent calls being made as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead of an ID, there can only be only one element with a particular ID on a page and jQuery will only act on the first one on the page it encounters.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".detay-menu-toggle-right").click(function(){
        $("#detay-wrapper-right").toggleClass("active");
        var paketnosu = $(this).data("paketno");
        var dataString = 'paketDetayi='+paketnosu;
        $.ajax({
            data: dataString,
            url: 'test3.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#detay-sidebar-wrapper-right").html(data);
            },
            error:
                function() {
                    alert('Not OKay');
                }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><a class="detay-menu-toggle-right" data-paketno="3512" href="#">Details</a></td>
<td><a class="detay-menu-toggle-right" data-paketno="3841" href="#">Details</a></td>
```

Comment: I changed the IDs but the result did not change. Could it be a problem in the general Div structure?

Comment: rememer to also change it there:   $(".detay-menu-toggle-right").click(function(){